# Parameter constraints without generics

Tags: c#, oop

Given the following example...

```
public class Example
{
    public static T GetDefaultValue<T>()
    {
    // return ???
    }
}
```

Without using generics, what approach could I use to constrain the type passed in to the GetDefaultValue function to a class with a parameterless constructor that implements IDisposable?
How would I instantiate an instance of the that type to return from the GetDefaultValue function?

Comment: I don't understand, your example class has the generic `T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused by what you mean.. but instead of using generics (without generics?) you can constrain the type to an interface.

```
public ISomeInterface GetDefaultValue(ISomeInterface theObject)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With generics, you can do

```
public static T GetDefaultValue<T>() where T : new(), IDisposable
{
   return new T();
}
```

Whatever type you set `T` to be must have a default constructor, though. This way, calling `GetDefaultValue()` will get you the precise type you need without the need to cast as you would have to if `GetDefaultValue()` returned an `IDisposable`.

I assume you didn't want a generics solution because the ability to instantiate a generic type is not well-known. I personally came across this by accident, and boy, is it a life saver!